# How do I act on a suggested edit that only updates the "status" of a question?

Tags: discussion

During review of "suggested edit" I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5245024) post.
Not being really sure about what to do with it I have clicked on skip.

I was tempted to mark it as not approved because **the suggested edit does not make any improvement of the post**. The attempt made by the OP that suggested the edit is to mark the question has solved but this should be done using the questions/answers features and not adding the status of the question in the title.

Should I have rejected the suggested edit according to the above view? Which is your opinion?

Comment: PS. [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1759128/itachiuchiha) should have been banned from reviewing for [approving **this**](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5245024)!

Comment: That's one more type of review audit that SE could create - audits that introduce "[solved]" or "[on hold]" to a post.

Comment: @S.L.Barth so you issued a list of posts to be edited.

Comment: @FeliceM Seriously, there are far worse edits than adding "[solved]" to a question. But since it would be a textbook example of an invalid edit, IMHO it would make a good review audit.

Comment: [That particular search](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3606681/ashish-shah?tab=questions) shows this user adding [Solved] to half his own questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should have rejected it and as you have noticed **"the suggested edit does not make any improvement of the post"** and that is exactly the point.

When a question is "solved" one of the answers is marked as accepted by the OP. Any title edits, such as status, should be rejected as too minor or invalid edit with an emphasis on the second one.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my understanding.